# SSH connecting on port 22 but times out on 443

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, putty, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I'm trying to connect to an ssh sever running on cygwin on my home computer through putty on my laptop, this works fine both inside my network and outside on port 22 but on port 443 it times out. Which is a bit of a problem as the network I'm going to be connecting from prevents me from using 22. I assume its a port forwarding issue but I've set up a rule in my router setting (isp provided BT HomeHub 3 Type A) but it doesn't seem to have opened the port. Any ideas on how to solve the issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: And is the server listening on port 443?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that I changed the sshd_config so it is Port 22 Port 443. I should get more sleep.

Comment: Did you restart sshd server? Do you have the port open in firewall? Does sshd have access to this port through SELinux or other control mecahnisms? Too much question unanswered.

Comment: Yes it's been restarted and the ports are open in the firewall, for your last question I'm not to sure how to check that.

Comment: Check if something else is running on port 443  and pc firewall rule.

Answer (score 6):

When you telnet (or nc) to a port that has an ssh server listening, you should obtain a string of characters, something like

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
```

If you don't obtain a string like that, then you are not speaking to an ssh server, and if you try speaking ssh to it, then your client will time out.

If it doesn't work, change your server back to port 22 so that ssh works again, and check how it looks. Try from the server itself. Change to port 443 and try again from localhost. Once that is OK, try from outside your server. If it does work from localhost but not from the outside, your problem is either port redirection, filtering, or some other kind of firewall.

In the unlikely case where you get the OpenSSH string but the OpenSSH client still times out, your problem is different, and you'll need to provide the -vvv output from ssh. You might have an MTU problem.